# How to get Distance in KM in this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, orm

```
$salons = Salon::select('salons.*')
    ->selectRaw('( 6371* acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                   cos( radians( lat ) )
                   * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                   ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                   sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                 ) AS distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])
    ->havingRaw("distance < 25")
    ->where("category_Id" , "=" , $id)
    ->get();
```

this query gives me this-

```
"distance": 0.05205731665026305, I want distance like this 1.2KM
```

i try but did not find get solution

Comment: you need to explain your question and query better

Comment: you can include the `concat` in the query, so you don't need to loop it and change the results

Comment: In spherical geometry it is never enough to get a distance as an angle. Imagine the distance between two points sitting both on the equator and separated 1 degree vs. two points near the north pole also separated by 1 degree (about 120 km vs. few meters).

Answer (score 3):

Better way will be to use PHP. SQL calculations are expensive. In certain raw counts difference can be 30sec vs 0.04 sec ;)

```
public function scopeDistance($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude, $distance)
    {
        $between_coords = \App\Services\PlaceServices::calcCoordinates($from_longitude, $from_latitude, $distance);

        return $query
            ->where(function ($q) use ($between_coords) {
                $q->whereBetween('places.longitude', [$between_coords['min']['lng'], $between_coords['max']['lng']]);
            })
            ->where(function ($q) use ($between_coords) {
                $q->whereBetween('places.latitude', [$between_coords['min']['lat'], $between_coords['max']['lat']]);
            });
    }
```

and calcCoodinates()

```
public static function calcCoordinates($longitude, $latitude, $radius = 20)
    {
        $lng_min = $longitude - $radius / abs(cos(deg2rad($latitude)) * 69);
        $lng_max = $longitude + $radius / abs(cos(deg2rad($latitude)) * 69);
        $lat_min = $latitude - ($radius / 69);
        $lat_max = $latitude + ($radius / 69);

        return [
            'min' => [
                'lat' => $lat_min,
                'lng' => $lng_min,
            ],
            'max' => [
                'lat' => $lat_max,
                'lng' => $lng_max,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Then just use `YourModel::distance($lat, $lon, $km)->get()`

Comment: is this the distance as circle? or square? e.g. lat lng min max makes one think it isnt round as you only have 2 points

Comment: It is square. I think it is small price for better performance

Answer (score 0):

for obtaining the `km`  you should use `111.045 km` per degree (as an approximation)

```
   ( 111.045 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                       cos( radians( lat ) )
                       * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                       ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                       sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
$data = DB::table('salons AS S')
                ->selectRaw("
                        ( FLOOR(6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( '$lat' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( S.lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( S.lng ) - RADIANS( '$lng' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( '$lat' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( S.lat ) ) )) ) distance")
                ->havingRaw("distance < 25")
                ->where("category_Id" , "=" , $id)
                ->get();
```

$lat, $lng are variables.