# How to Calculate Distance in laravel using lat long

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

How can i calculate distance in laravel5.5 with SQL query ?
My code mention below.

```
$specialProducts = Products::select('products.id', 'products.name', 'products.product_img', 'products.slug', 'products.price','products.lat','(3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS($lat))* COS(RADIANS(22.2765097))* COS(RADIANS(70.792523) - RADIANS(70.7583265))+ SIN(RADIANS(22.2897874))* SIN(RADIANS(22.2765097)))) AS distance')
            ->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.id', '=', 'products.sub_category_id')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
            ->join('store', 'store.id', '=', 'products.store_id')
            ->where('products.status', 1)
            ->where('products.special', 1)

            ->orderBy('products.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Comment: @martinstoeckli yes bro

Comment: where is your lat long values??

Comment: 22.2765097 / 70.792523 add static value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to do it with php instead of mysql. Check my response here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50040011/1262144

Answer (score 2):

If you have the values for the latitude and longitude in your DB, then you can get the distance between them using the SQl query as in the below example using raw SQL with DB:raw().

```
$lat = 41.118491 // user's latitude
$lng = 25.404509 // user's longitude

SELECT *, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) 
* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS calculated_distance 
FROM settings as T 
HAVING calculated_distance <= (SELECT distance FROM settings WHERE sid=T.sid) 
ORDER BY distance_calc
```

If you want to get distance in miles instead of kilometers, replace 6371 with 3959.

The calculation process may take a long time so, you might want to cache the result for next use.