# Laravel MySql Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public static function rsine($coordinates)
{
    return '(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) 
    * cos(radians(`lat`)) 
    * cos(radians(`lng`) 
    - radians(' . $coordinates['longitude'] . ')) 
    + sin(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) 
    * sin(radians(`lat`))))';
}
```

Output:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(28.392200)) \n    * cos(radians(`lat`)) \n    * cos(ra' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select *, *, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(28.392200)) \n    * cos(radians(`lat`)) \n    * cos(radians(`lng`) \n    - radians(77.320801)) \n    + sin(radians(28.392200)) \n    * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS distance from `locations` where `users`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` and (6371 * acos(cos(radians(28.392200)) \n    * cos(radians(`lat`)) \n    * cos(radians(`lng`) \n    - radians(77.320801)) \n    + sin(radians(28.392200)) \n    * sin(radians(`lat`)))) < 8.04672 order by `distance` asc) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)",

Comment: How do you use `rsine()`?

Comment: $coordinates = ['latitude' => '28.392200', 'longitude' => '77.320801'];

  $rsine = Location::rsine($coordinates);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, next time try to formulate more like a question if you ask help on this platform.

Secondly it never a good idea to integrate variables directly in you query. This will make your queries vulnarable for sql injections. Basics can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions).

By looking at your query (in the error) we can see you are to get all columns twice by using the `*` wildcard.

```
select
    *
from
    users
where
    exists (
        select
            *,
            *, <-- This will throw a syntax error.
            (6371 * acos(co ... the rest of the distance calculation
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to name your method scopeRsine(). 
But don't use mysql for this. Use php instead. Check my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50040011/1262144